# Django troubles with forms and csrf tokens

Tags: python, django, forms, csrf, django-csrf

I'm trying to get a pretty simple email form working. The form is only one field (email).

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template import RequestContext
from launchpage.models import EmailForm

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        form = EmailForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            clean_data = form.clean_data
            # send an email
                    thank_you = "Thanks for signing up"
            return render_to_response('launch.html', {'thank_you': thank_you})
    else:
        form = EmailForm()
    return render_to_response('launch.html', {'form': form,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**launch.html** (relevant part)

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        {% if thank_you %}
             <div class="alert alter-info">
             {{ thank_you }}
             </div>
        {% else %}
            <form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">{% csrf_token %}
            Or stay updated by email (no spam, pinky swear) &nbsp;&nbsp;
            {{ form.email }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
        </form>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

**middleware in settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

---

Current result: the page displays as if there was no templating involved. I see the form and the submit button is there, but no email field. Also no csrf hidden field. I must be missing something stupid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this:

`from launchpage.models import EmailForm`

shouldn't be `from launchpage.forms import EmailForm`

The other problem you have is `{'form': form,}` needs to be `{'form': form}`

Finally, `{{ form.email }}` should be simply `{{ form }}`

Final tip - consider using the [`render` shortcut](http://django.me/render) which sends the appropriate request context automatically.

Comment: I don't know why you got a downvote, it wasn't me. I fixed what you mentioned and it didn't work at first. Then I tried restarting apache and it worked! Thanks